# How to evaluate postfix when there is no whitespace?

Tags: c, stack, evaluation, postfix-mta

My program evaluates postfix expressions well when there are white spaces, but a simple one like '56*' with no white space cannot be evaluated. How do I do that?

Also, "1.2e3 -3.4e-1 /" it cannot understand the (-1) of e notation and takes it as +1. This is another problem. I need to adjust the code to adapt to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 50 /* Size of Stack */

double s[SIZE];
int peak=-1; /* Global declarations */
char pofx[50];

double pop()
{                      /* Function for POP operation */
  return(s[peak--]);
}

double push(double elem) {
  if (peak + 1 >= SIZE) {
    printf("Stack overflow\n");
    return 0;
  }
  s[++peak] = elem;
}

void main()
{                         /* Main Program */
    printf("Enter the Postfix Expression:");
    // fgets(pofx,100,stdin); // 100??
    fgets(pofx, sizeof pofx, stdin); // better
    postfixtoresult();
    printf("Result: %lf\n",s[peak]);
}

void postfixtoresult()
{            
  int i=0;
  const char *st = pofx;

  while (*st) {
    char *end; //location to store end of FP parsing
    double value = strtod(st, &end);
    if (end > st) {
      push(value);
      st = end; 
    } else if (isspace((unsigned char) *st)) {
      st++;
    } else {
      switch (*st) {
        case '+':push(pop() + pop());break; // pop order irrelevant
        case '-':{ double t = pop(); push(pop() - t);break; } // pop order             relevant
        case '*':push(pop() * pop());break; // pop order irrelevant
        case '/':{ double u = pop(); push(pop() / u);break; }  // pop order relevant
        case '^':{ double v = pop(); push(pow(pop(),v));break; }  // pop order relevant

        default: {
          printf("Input invalid operator: character code %d\n", *st);
          return 0;
        } 
      }  // end switch
      st++;
    }
  }     
}
```

Comment: You have to decide whether you only ever enter single digit numbers, or whether you can enter multi-digit numbers. If you only allow single-digit numbers, then you can read the number as a digit (not using `strtod()`) automatically get `5`, `6`, and `*` from `56*`. If you allow multi-digit numbers, then `56*` is an error; there aren't enough numbers on the stack for the `*` operator to use.  You'll choose one or the other — it doesn't much matter which.  Only allowing single digit numbers on input is rather restrictive.  I recommend that you insist that users separate numbers with white space.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler. What & how should I change the code if I decide to keep input as single digit so as to solve the no whitespace issue and at the same time, accept e notation as negative integers as well?

Comment: You have to redo the code where you currently call `strtod()`.  But it frankly makes no sense to allow exponent notation with single digit numbers.  Signs can be handled more easily.

Comment: Last request @JonathanLeffler If you could just tell me how I can evaluate "56*" with no whitespace keeping the strtod function, because the requirement for my work is it has to be able to handle extra whitespace as well as no whitespace. How do you suggest handling the negative sign after e?

Comment: You can’t use `strtod()` and work with single-digit numbers.  Or, more precisely, the shenanigans required are sufficiently grotesque that you don’t want to consider indulging in them.

Comment: If `56*` is entered instead of `5 6 *`, it should be an error.

Comment: The opposite of "_extra white-space_" is **not** "_no white-space_"... it is "_bare-minimum white-space_". In the case of adjacent (potentially multi-digit) numbers, you need at least one element of white-space (e.g. `5 6*` could be valid; `56*` or `56 *` cannot). `5 6*` does not contain "extra" white-space; just the bare minimum. (An alternative _might_ be to have a "_number separator_", e.g. `5,6*` but you still need _something_ between the two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct a greedy scanner that eats valid characters until the next char cannot be part of the new token, then you have probably to `ungetc(3)` the last char.

Below is a scanner (with a `main()` function to test it) that parses integer (signed or unsigned) and deals with spaces (or signs) correctly (I think :) )  Feel free to use it or modify at your need.  Beware that a plus or minus sign in front of a number will be stuck to it (you can unstick by inserting a space)

If you need to parse more complex things (like floating numbers) then I'll recommend you to read and use `lex(1)`/`flex(1)` scanner generator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_ID 64 /* must be at least two.  Routine assumes that */

/* single chars include values 0..255 */
#define TOK_EOF     256
#define TOK_ERR     257
#define TOK_INT     258

union tokenval {
    int num;  /* in case we return an integer */
    /* in case you scan other tokens with specific values, 
     * e.g. floating point numbers, you can add to this union. */
};

/* lexical scanner with one character of lookahead.
 * It recognises:
 * integers (regexp: [+-]?[0-9][0-9]*)
 * symbols (regexp: .)
 * comments (regexp: #.*\n) ( these are ignored)
 */
int scan(FILE *in, union tokenval *val)
{
    int c;
    int result = TOK_ERR;

    while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {

        if (isspace(c)) /* skip spaces */
            continue;

        if (c == '#') { /* comment */
            while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF && (c != '\n')) continue;
            /* c == EOF || c == '\n' */
            if (c == EOF) return TOK_EOF;
            /* c == '\n' */
            continue;
        }

        if (isalpha(c)) { /* identifier */
            char *p = val->id;
            size_t l = 1;
            *p++ = c; /* add read char */
            while (isalnum(c = fgetc(in))) {
                if (l < MAX_ID-1) { /* add only if we have space */
                    *p++ = c; l++;
                }
            }
            *p = '\0'; /* terminate the identifier properly */
            /* !isalnum(c) */
            ungetc(c, in);
            return TOK_ID;
        }

        /* possible signed number */
        switch(c) {
        case '+': /* possible signed number */
        case '-':
            result = c; /* save the read char in result until we know
                           if we have a trailing number. */
            c = fgetc(in);
        }

        /* result in {TOK_ERR, '+', '-'} */
        if (isdigit(c)) { /* integer */
            val->num = c - '0';
            while (isdigit(c = fgetc(in))) {
                val->num *= 10;
                val->num += c - '0';
            }
            /* !isdigit(c) */
            ungetc(c, in);
            if (result == '-') val->num = -val->num;
            return TOK_INT;
        }

        return result == TOK_ERR ? c : result;
    } /* while */
    /* c == EOF */
    return TOK_EOF;
} /* scan */

int main() {
    int tok;
    union tokenval val;

#define EOL() puts("")
#define P(tok) printf("[%s-%d]", #tok, (tok))
#define PS(tok) printf("['%c'-%d]\n", (tok), (tok))
    do {
        tok = scan(stdin, &val);
        switch(tok) {
        case TOK_ERR: P(TOK_ERR); EOL(); break;
        case TOK_INT: P(TOK_INT); printf(":%d\n", val.num); break;
        case TOK_EOF: P(TOK_EOF); EOL(); break;
        default: PS(tok); break;
        } /* switch */
    } while (tok != TOK_EOF);
} /* main */
```

## NOTE

the problem (and the reason I have not included it) with the scanner shown, not dealing with the `e-1` trailing suffix in a floating point number, is that this requires a scanner capable of backtracking more than one char (if you read a valid floating point number ---e.g. `2.71`---, followed by `e-` you have still to read another char to decide if you enlarge your floating point number, so in case you don't get a digit after the `-` sign, you have to push back the already read `-` and the `e` char (in that order) to be included when the next token is read.  I have not included a scanner capable or reading floating point numbers, because is quite easy to solve that problem with `lex(1)`/`flex(1)`, and it adds much complexity to the code shown.

## NOTE 2

If you use `lex(1)`/`flex(1)`, the scanner specification for the above scanner can be:

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* single chars include values 0..255 */
#define TOK_EOF     0
#define TOK_ERR     256
#define TOK_INT     257
#define TOK_DBL     258
#define TOK_ID      259

%}

%%
[+-]?[0-9][0-9]*                                      { return TOK_INT; /* integer */ }
[+-]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]*)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)? { return TOK_DBL; /* double */ }
#.*\n                                                 ; /* comment, ignored */
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*                                  { return TOK_ID; /* ident */ }
[ \t\n]                                               ; /* space, ignored */
.                                                     { return yytext[0]; /* the operator char */ }
%%

int main()
{
    int tok;
    do {
        tok = yylex();
        switch(tok) {
#define C(ptok) case TOK_##ptok: do{printf("[TOK_"#ptok"-%d]: %s\n", TOK_##ptok, yytext);}while(0)
        C(EOF); break;
        C(ERR); return 1;
        C(INT); break;
        C(DBL); break;
        C(ID); break;
        default: printf("['%c'-%d]\n", tok, tok); break;
        }
    } while(tok != TOK_EOF);
    return 0;
} /* main */

int yywrap() /* so we don't need to link with -ll */
{
    return 1;
}
```